# Create New View for Google Analytics with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was wondering how to create a new view for google analytics with ruby using the current 0.8.6 version of the library or otherwise? This would be after I have gotten the appropriate access token.

The specific call is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert

Any tips would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the Google Ruby Client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/

and the source for the Google Analytics Library:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/AnalyticsV3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features,  [request access to the](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform) beta

It can take a while to get access it took me over a month you might want to start there first.   While you are waiting I suggest you look at the normal ruby google analytics core reporting API examples once you are familiar with those you should be able to get the insert views working.